# Pagination option added to top of the answer section

Tags: support, design, pagination

When I have searched with the term [answers:100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a100) (find the post with 100+ answers), I can see the pagination option in the top of the answer section too. Previously the pagination was only in the bottom of the answer section.

I checked when was the change introduced to the Stack Exchange in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/312043) post, and didn't find any reference.

So the pagination added to the top of answer section is intentionally?

> [image: top pagination]

Comment: I doubt it was added by mistake. And if so, it's a good mistake. (Since SE might now remove it if it wasn't on purpose, not sure it's good to "report" it. ;))